# Can squirrel remember the column layouts of the Content tab?

Tags: squirrel-sql

I've started using squirrel and generally like it. But one thing that bugs me is that it doesn't seem to remember when I've rearranged how a table looks in the Content tab. If I'm looking at a table or view and reorder and resize the columns in a way that makes it easier for me to read, then I switch briefly to another table and then switch back, all my tweaks to how the columns look are gone. Is there a way to cause squirrel to keep/remember how I rearrange things?

Comment: I wish it would remember the sort of column names as well when looking at schema.

Answer (score 1):

Column order should never matter in a database, but I see why you might want this.  As far as I know the only way to do this is drop the table and recreate with correct order.